# USB to ethernet not working on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: samsung, usb-on-the-go, usb-host-mode, ethernet

I have Samsung Galaxy S Blaze with the following specs

- Samsung Galaxy S Blaze 4G SGH-T769
- Android version = 4.0.4
- Baseband version = T769UVMB1
- Kernel version = 3.0.8-perf-T769ULVH5-CL990184
- Model Number = SGH-T769

I am following [this thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/result-usb-otg-ethernet-t2509382) as I had the same problem reported on page 4.

I am using AX88772 compatible USB to Ethernet adapter (pluggable USB 2.0) and have successfully compiled drivers for Android ICS. I have also put the `asix.ko` into `/system/lib/modules` directory and loaded it with `insmod`.

I have connected the Samsung phone with Inateck USB 3.0 four-port hub where I have also connected pluggable USB 2.0 ethernet adapter. But the ethernet is not working:

```
root@hammerhead:/ # netcfg eth0 up
netcfg eth0 up
action 'up' failed (No such device)

1|root@hammerhead:/ # netcfg
netcfg
rev_rmnet8 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 72:21:40:52:3e:20
rev_rmnet4 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 9e:5b:78:bd:4b:89
rev_rmnet2 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 a6:e7:62:d2:fc:c5
rev_rmnet3 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 8e:9d:a8:c7:cc:94
rev_rmnet7 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 ea:82:2f:72:9d:fc
rev_rmnet5 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 82:db:fe:b7:a9:1d
rev_rmnet6 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 be:db:eb:ab:b3:17
rev_rmnet1 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 ae:87:e2:c4:c8:4e
rev_rmnet0 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 4a:49:58:b0:1d:e4
rmnet4 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet2 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet3 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet7 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet5 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet6 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet1 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet0 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
p2p0 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 8e:3a:e3:4c:21:28\
sit0 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00000080 00:00:00:00:00:00
lo UP 127.0.0.1/8 0x00000049 00:00:00:00:00:00\
wlan0 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0 0x00001002 8c:3a:e3:4c:21:28

root@hammerhead:/ # ifconfig eth0
ifconfig eth0
eth0: No such device
```

There is no mention of OTG driver and USB host driver. Are they installed by default? How do I check if I have these installed? Or, are they not needed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got the solution. I was using Inateck HB4004G 4-port USB3.0 hub. I should have used an on-the-go (OTG) cable instead. When I used the OTG cable, the ethernet interface `eth0` came up.

Here is the OTG cable for your convenience.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some older USB OTG ports needed a powered OTG.  Even powered hubs didn't work on my Motorola Droid 1, whereas that did. Also, some USB Ethernet chips don't work on Android.